# Keep getting an error about type match. Not sure what it means or how to fix it

Tags: c++, vector, compiler-errors, maps

```
'void std::vector<_Ty>::push_back(_Ty &&)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const
std::vector<_Ty>' to 'std::string &&'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=std::string
1>          ]
1>          Reason: cannot convert from 'const std::vector<_Ty>' to 'std::string'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=std::string
1>          ]
1>          No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
```

my private looks like this:

```
private:
    map<string, vector<string> > mymap;
};
```

and the error the function occurs looks like this:

```
void MiniSearch::NotFunction(const string q1, const string q2, vector<string>& ReturnVec) const
{
    // checks for q1 and that q2 isnt in
    if (mymap.find(q1) != mymap.end() && mymap.find(q2) == mymap.end())
    {
        // q1 in map q2 not in map else return
        const vector<string>& temp = mymap.find(q1)->second;
        unsigned int i = 0;
        for (std::vector<string>::const_iterator it = temp.begin(); it != temp.end(); ++it)
        {
            if (ReturnVec.empty())
                ReturnVec.push_back(*it);

            else
            if (i < ReturnVec.size() && ReturnVec[i] != *it)
                ReturnVec.push_back(*it);
            ++i;;
        }
    }
    ReturnVec.push_back(mymap.find(q1)->second); // ERROR
}
```

How do I fix this? Is my map not using the right data structures? Am I missing something in private? The way I wrote the code logically makes since to me just not sure why its not working.

Comment: You're trying to `push_back` an entire vector onto `ReturnVec`?

Comment: I have file names (.txt) that I want to pushed onto the returnVec, once done it will return all documents that a particular word input was located in.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you don't want `push_back`, since you're trying to append one vector to another.  Instead, you want something like this:

```
ReturnVec.insert(ReturnVec.end(), mymap.find(q1)->second.begin(), mymap.find(q1)->second.end());
```

Note also that all those calls to `mymap.find(q1)` and `mymap.find(q2)` are going to re-search the map, adding tons of cycles.  You ought to consider declaring an iterator and performing the `find` only once for each:

```
auto q1_it = mymap.find(q1);
auto q2_it = mymap.find(q2);
```

Or if you can't do C++11:

```
map< string, vector<string> >::iterator q1_it = mymap.find(q1);
map< string, vector<string> >::iterator q2_it = mymap.find(q2);
```

That should give you a noticeable performance lift.

Applying those iterators to my answer above:

```
ReturnVec.insert(ReturnVec.end(), q1_it->second.begin(), q1_it->second.end());
```